# Getting loss value as 0 when training a neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, loss

I am unsure if I should be pasting the whole code but here it is:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np  
import requests 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

BATCH_SIZE = 20


#Get data
birthdata_url = 'http://springer.bme.gatech.edu/Ch17.Logistic/Logisticdat/lowbwt.dat'
birth_file = requests.get(birthdata_url)
birth_data = birth_file.text.split('\r\n')[5:]
birth_data = np.array([[x for x in y.split(' ') if len(x)>=1] for y in birth_data[1:] if len(y)>=1])

#Get x and y vals
y_vals = np.array([x[1] for x in birth_data]).reshape((-1,1))
x_vals = np.array([x[2:10] for x in birth_data])

#Split data
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_vals,y_vals,test_size=0.3)


#Placeholders
x_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,8])
y_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,1])


#Define our Neural Network

def init_weight(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=shape,stddev=0.1))

def init_bias(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=shape))

def fully_connected(inp_layer,weights,biases):
    return tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inp_layer,weights)+biases)

def nn(x):
    w1 = init_weight([8,25])
    b1 = init_bias([25])
    layer1 = fully_connected(x,w1,b1)

    w2 = init_weight([25,10])
    b2 = init_bias([10])
    layer2 = fully_connected(layer1,w2,b2)

    w3 = init_weight([10,3])
    b3 = init_bias([3])
    layer3 = fully_connected(layer2,w3,b3)

    w4 = init_weight([3,1])
    b4 = init_bias([1])
    final_output = fully_connected(layer3,w4,b4)


    return final_output




#Predicted values.
y_ = nn(x_data)


#Loss and training step.
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_data,logits=y_))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

#Initalize session and global variables
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

#Accuracy
def get_accuracy(logits,labels):
    batch_predicitons = np.argmax(logits,axis=1)
    num_correct = np.sum(np.equal(batch_predicitons,labels))
    return(100*num_correct/batch_predicitons.shape[0])



loss_vec = []
for i in range(500):
    #Get random indexes and create batches. 
    rand_index = np.random.choice(len(x_train),size=BATCH_SIZE)

    #x and y batch.
    rand_x = x_train[rand_index]
    rand_y = y_train[rand_index]

    #Run the training step.
    sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x_data:rand_x,y_data:rand_y})

    #Get the current loss. 
    temp_loss = sess.run(loss,feed_dict={x_data:x_test,y_data:y_test})
    loss_vec.append(temp_loss)

    if(i+1)%20==0:
        print("Current Step is: {}, Loss: {}"
            .format((i+1),
            temp_loss))

    #print("-----Test Accuracy: {}-----".format(get_accuracy(logits=sess.run(y_,feed_dict={x_data:x_test}),labels=y_test)))
```

When I run my program, I always get the loss value as 0 when training. I am unsure where the problem potentially is at. But I have a few ideas.

1)Could it be the way I create batches of data? It seems like an unusual way but as far as I am concerned, it should work by getting random indexes as in `rand_index = np.random.choice(len(x_train),size=BATCH_SIZE)` .

2)This does not make sense, but could it be because the data is "small data"?

3)Any simple error in the code?

4)Or I really have loss as 0. (which is the most improbable case)

I would be more than happy if you could additionally point out what I should avoid in doing in the code above.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't immediately see what is wrong but why don't you print out the predictions to help with debugging. At least that way you could double-check the computation of the loss.

Comment: @Aaron I get zeros in shape `(20,1)` interesting...

Comment: Another thing I would do to debug this is remove some of the hidden layers to make the network simpler.

Comment: Also you shouldn't have a relu on your last layer.

Comment: @Aaron May I ask the reason? Is it a specific case for relu?

Comment: Because you are already using the softmax as a non linearity on the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran your code and these are the bugs I found.

1. It looks like your input data is strings. You should convert it to floats.
2. Don't use a relu on the last layer. It should feed directly into the loss function without a non-linearity.
3. You should be using the `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` function instead of the softmax one. Sigmoid is for binary classification and softmax is for multi-class classification.
4. It's possible that your learning rate is too high. I would try a lower one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out thr bugs. It helps a lot. Now I know how important the choice of entropy function is.

Comment: I have done  the tweaks multiple times. But I still fail. Were you able to get a legitimate result? I always get accuracy as 100% in every training step.

Comment: Ahh I see. Now I can see my mistake. Thank you so much for your effort and help! May I ask one more question. After the training is done, shouldn't the NN return either 0 or 1? Because it returns values ranging from -3 to 1. Any ideas on that?  Thanks a billion again

Comment: You can take the output from y_ and if it is less than 0 consider it to be a  0 and if it is greater than zero consider it to be a 1. Alternatively, you can compute probs = tf.sigmoid(y_) and then you will get the estimated probability of belonging to the positive class.